# Shell expansion for arguments?

Tags: bash, shell, osx, variable, arguments

For example:

`mkdir ~/{1,2,3}`

Creates directories `~/1`, `~/2`, and `~/3`. It equates to:

```
mkdir ~/1
mkdir ~/2
mrdir ~/3
```

But, using the same syntax in the case of `CMD < argument >` :

```
brew {install, update, doctor}
```

...amounts to nonsense as interpreted by the shell. It doesn’t mean:

```
brew install
brew update
brew doctor
```

It’s easy to make a quick script, but *there must* be a simpler way using expansion or substitution within bash. What am I missing?

Running `Bash 3.2.57(1)-release` on `OS X 10.10.2`

Comment: Your question isn't clear as to what you are trying to achieve and what is the issue you are facing. Can you try to explain better?

Comment: @rahul thanks for your response. I’ve (hopefully) clarified what I’m trying to ask.

Comment: `mkdir ~/{1,2,3}` does not expand to three commands, it expands to one command with three arguments `mkdir ~/1 ~/2 ~/3`. It is `mkdir` which interprets multiple arguments as separate operations. `brew` doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xargs` seems to be what you want:

```
echo install update doctor | xargs -n1 brew
```

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.

Comment: A slightly shorter command which does the same: `xargs -n1 brew <<<"install update doctor"`

Comment: But keep in mind that "here strings" aren't available in some shells.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the first space and remove the other spaces:

```
$ printf "'%s'\n" brew\ {install,update,doctor}
'brew install'
'brew update'
'brew doctor'
```

If `brew` is a command just write (also without the spaces):

```
brew {install,update,doctor}
```

like with your mkdir example:

```
mkdir {install,update,doctor}
```

You need no external process or piping to do that; all can be done in your `bash` shell.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Even without whitespace, `brew {x,y,z}` doesn’t expand to `brew x; brew y; brew z`  for whatever reason.

Comment: Works for me. What `bash` version are you running?

Comment: `Bash 3.2.57(1)-release` . It doesn’t execute past `update` in this particular case. Also, if you switch up the argument order, it fails completely. Perhaps it’s `brew` itself. Will try with a builtin command. Thanks for assistance.

Comment: I tried with bash 3.2.48(21). It worked for me, e.g., with `mkdir` or `printf`.

Comment: that syntax seems to fail when executing more than one argument for a given command. Example: `diskutil {list,activity}` results in `Could not find disk: activity`.

Comment: @Janis this doesn't work for brew, because `brew {install,update,doctor}` expands to `brew install update doctor`, which is an invalid call for `brew`. It works for `mkdir` and `printf` because `mkdir install update doctor` and `printf install update doctor` are valid calls.

Answer (score 1):

How about (notice the backslashes, all important):

```
echo brew\ {install,update,doctor}\;| bash
```

the first pattern (arguments for `echo`) will expand thusly:

```
echo brew install; brew update; brew doctor;
```

which is then echoed, producing this output:

```
brew install; brew update; brew doctor;
```

which we pipe to a new bash instance.